# Convenient way to switch Windows default playback device

Tags: windows-7, audio, playback

I have loudspeakers and headphones, both of which are connected to the PC all the time (the headphones are wireless so what is actually connected to the PC is a USB cable from the cradle). If I want to switch from one to the other, I need to navigate to the *Sound* control panel, select the other speakers and click *Set Default*.

These is quite a lot of steps, isn't there a way to switch playback devices more easily using some 3rd party software or a clever hack? Something like a desktop gadget or Windows task bar jump list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use the [SoundSwitch](http://soundswitch.codeplex.com/).

[image]

You can also quickly access using `mmsys.cpl` in dialog box ([image: i2] + <kbd>R</kbd>).

Comment: Win+R and `mmsys.cpl` isn't faster than Win+"sou"+Enter :)

Answer (score 0):

Another great way to conveniently switch the default audio device is to use command line nircmd.exe.

Download source file: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html

To create a Nircmd shortcut right-click on:

1. the desktop -> *New* -> *Shortcut* and enter the command into the box
   (nircmd.exe setdefaultsounddevice [Device Name]),
2. Then click *Next* and give it a name such as "Switch to Speakers".
3. Double clicking Nircmd will copy it to the Windows directory for
       you, so if you don't do that,you will need to supply a path to the
           nircmd.exe in the shortcut.

[image]
<sup>**Screenshot of how to do it on desktop**</sup>